# Project size increased to 716 MB after adding Realm DB

Tags: xcode, realm, cocoapods, swift5

The project is just a simple notepad but the size increased to 716 MB after adding Realm DB. What could be the problem ? There is a warning in Xcode as well: "/:1:1: Umbrella header for module 'Realm' does not include header '/core/realm.h'"

Comment: Welcome to SO. That question is super vague - perhaps the size increased because you added data to it? Or maybe you're code has an infinite loop that created 100,000 objects? Or maybe you have video or pictures included? We need a bit more to go on. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Good evening! As i said before the app is just a simple notepad, without any videos and pic. All i tried to save is some  pieces of texts to test app and database.

Comment: Cool. I got ya - added an answer/explanation. What you're seeing is about right.

Comment: The second question may be that your cocoapds needs updating: `sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin`.

Comment: So does it mean that all projects using Realm DB are about 1 GB and that's a normal behavior? what a pity. But anyway, thank you for your answers!

Comment: Well, no. I added an edit to the answer: Remember there are a lot of additional files and 'stuff' that may exist within a project development folder that may not be part of the final project. For example, I have a small ToDo project where the product development folder is about 512Mb. However, the built app itself is 39Mb. In the *Realm/core/realm-monorepo.xcframework* folder, there are supporting files for macOS, tVOS, iOS, watchOS etc, so a lot of extraneous stuff that has nothing to do with the project on your device. If my answer helped, be sure to accept it so it can help others.

Comment: But tell me please, Should I do something about this large app or leave it as it is? the problem arose when I could not upload the project to the repository on github because of it's size

Comment: Well, see the details in my answer as you can easily make a project folder smaller. But I am not sure if you're referring to the project folder (which contains your source code) or to the app itself. I think you're referring to the project folder and in that case, as mentioned in my answer there are a number of things that can be safely removed to reduce the folder size.

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to the [github for Realm releases](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/releases) you can see the RealmSwift SDK comes in at 871 Mb zipped (2Gb unzipped!).

[image]

If the examples and so forth are removed, it's still about 525Mb so what you're seeing in your question is about right.

[image]

**EDIT**

There are a lot of additional files and 'stuff' that may exist within a project development folder that may not be part of the final project because the SDK may need to support multiple devices.

For example, in the *Realm/core/realm-monorepo.xcframework* folder, there are supporting files for macOS/tVOS/iOS/watchOS etc, so a lot of extraneous stuff that has nothing to do with the project on your device. If you are not using that part of the SDK, those can be removed to make the project file smaller.

Additionally, the 10.7.2 SDK that's downloaded from github has a bunch of example projects and code that can also be removed.