# Reduce MongoRealm (Realm , Realm Database) size in swift package manager

Tags: swift, mongodb, realm, swift-package-manager

The mongoRealm SDK is huge in size and I would like to reduce it.

In it's readme they say we can opt out of using the precompiled version and build our own using the source and link this  - https://github.com/realm/jazzy

Very confused, Jazzy says it's a documentation tool

Comment: If the question is about the size of the SDK per this - *mongoRealm SDK is huge* - then I addressed that in the following answer [Realm Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66640047/project-size-increased-to-716-mb-after-adding-realm-db/66643367#66643367). If that's not the question, can you clarify?

Comment: @Jay My app went from kilobytes to 70 mb with high build times. I added the Realm Cocoa and realm core dependency from Swift Package manager. I want to optimise it and make it leaner.

Comment: I don't think that was caused directly by Realm. One of our apps has a fairly significant amount of code and it weighs in at 37Mb. I just crafted a brand new project, installed Realm via cocoapods and it comes in at 32Mb which is to be expected. You should try that process as well and see what a totally clean built app weighs in at. One thing we've seen people forget about is if they are including a bundled realm as that can quickly increase project size. Also, try CocoaPods instead of SPM as a test.

Comment: I deleted some UWP and examples files. The app size is still 72 mb but my build times have improved.

Comment: @Jay Ok when I archived it comes to 32mb. My real issue is with build times.

Comment: That's an improvement. Our project that's 37Mb after cleaning the build folder (Product Menu->Clean build folder) takes 47 seconds to *build* (not run as that could involve launching the simulator on iOS). Of course that's a complete re-compile of everything which is typically not needed during development. Subsequent builds take 4 seconds, which is the important measuring stick. This is on a 2017 27" iMac i7 with SSD. To reduce size, don't forget to remove unrelated supporting files - our app is macOS so we removed the iOS, Watch etc from the monorepo folder (see my link above)